# Converting UTC timestamp to a time value?

Tags: excel, time, utc

I'm doing an exercise where I have data with several entries of this type:

```
  "started_at": 1475499600.287,
```

Which is defined as:

> started_at: when the interval started, UTC Time

Ok, how can I convert it to a meaningful time (using Excel, for example) in some format (e.g. `dd/mm/yyyy hh:mm:ss`)?

Comment: @ScottCraner (does this even ping you?) - When I use that formula, `=(A2-DATE(1970,1,1))*86400` with OP's number (`1475...`), I don't get a date/time, nor a number that I can format as such.

Comment: No you need to use the second answer not the first.  That poster did it both ways. `(Unix Timestamp / 86400) + 24107` @BruceWayne

Comment: @ScottCraner - D'oh! Sorry, that does it :P

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For translating into GMT, you can use

```
=(((A1/60)/60)/24)+DATE(1970,1,1)
```

Your example time will become `03/10/2016 13:00:00`

Make sure to format the cell `dd/mm/yyyy hh:mm:ss`

Comment: That made the trick, thanks!